# MVC Ajax not loading Partial View in div, loading new page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm currently working with MVC 1.0 and have never worked with AJAX before and only have limited experience (started a little more than a week ago) with ASP.Net MVC. I'm trying to setup a table (that's built / is in a partial view) that's populated with information from a db that allows a user to quickly add pr remove records into or from the db right from the table. I'm trying to use AJAX to get this done because there is a lot of other information on the rest of the page that I don't want to have to reload. Here's a quick template.

row1: (text box) *Add*

row2: Name1 *Remove*

row3: Name2 *Remove*

So when a user wants to, they can enter a name into the (text box) hit *Add* and an action in the controller will add the entered name into the database and reload the partial view with the most up to date information.

So far I have been able to get the action method to be called, and add the record into the database. The problem is that it does not reload JUST the partial-view. It instead loads the partial-view as a whole new page and it's content is the only one that displays. (Instead of staying at /Project/Details/5, the page loads /Project/MembersDisplay)

In my master page I have:

```
<script src="<%= Links.Scripts.jquery_1_3_2_min_js %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Links.Scripts.MicrosoftAjax_js %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Links.Scripts.MicrosoftMvcAjax_js %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the controller I have:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public virtual ActionResult AddMember(FormCollection form)
    {
        MemberRepository repo = new MemberRepository();
        Member m = new Member();
        m.Id = Convert.ToInt32(form["Id"]);
        m.Name = form["name"];

        try{
            repo.addMember(m);
            repo.save();
        }
        catch{
            return View();
        }

        // Make a new IList of All Members in this current 
        //IList<Member> mems = (new PRDataContext()).Members_GetMembersById(m.Id).ToList<Member>();

       return View("MembersDisplay", members);
    }
```

The Partial view is

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<Application.Models.Member>>" %>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoffMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<table>
    <% if (Model.Count() > 0) { %>
        <% foreach (var p in ViewData.Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= Html.Encode(p.Name) %></td>
        <td><%= Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "AjaxDelete", new { p.Id, p.Name }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Delete?", HttpMethod = "AjaxDelete", UpdateTargetId = "results" })%></td>
    </tr>
        <% } %>
    <% } else { %>
    <tr>
        <td><b>There are no Members.</b></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

In the controller, I tried adding *if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()==true)* the branch never executed. I'm not sure if ajax isn't loading, or what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT** - Added missing code

Here's the details portion that uses the partial view:

```
<table>
<% Ajax.BeginForm("AddMember", "Project", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace}) { %>
<tr>
    <td align="left" colspan="2" style="background-color:#93B6E0;"><font style="color:#fff;"><b>Members</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="80%">
        <input type="hidden" name="prjId" value="<%= Html.Encode(Model.Id) %>" /><input type="text" name="name" style="width:120px;" />
    </td>
    <td width="20%">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div  id="results"><% Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Members.Views.MembersDisplay, Model.Members.ToList<Member>()); %></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're executing a postback instead of an ajax POST request.  Can you share the code that invokes your controller action?

Comment: Fixed it. Among other thing, the links to the .js files were wrong (thanks FireBug for pointing that one out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to MVC 2.0 as @RailRhoad suggested.

Then I moved the partial view to an area and has to change the path links to the .js files to be more explicit (T4MVC wasn't rendering the correct paths). Instead of

`<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

or

`<script src="<%= Links.Scripts.MicrosoftAjax_js %>" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I had to do

`<script src="../../../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Also, the action in the controller worked as @jim suggested by

```
return PartialView(MVC.ProjectDash.Project.Views.MembersDisplay, members);
```

Also, I removed the "InsertionMode=..." from

```
<% Ajax.BeginForm("AddMember", "Project", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace}) { %>
```

The biggest issue was the javascript files were not be linked up and referenced correctly. Once that was fixed, the other things quickly feel into place.

Answer (score 1):

Dirk - not sure if the complete code is there. however, from a brief glance, your returning:

```
return View("MembersDisplay", members);
```

when in fact, for a partial view, you should be returning something like:

```
return PartialView("MembersDisplay", members);
```

hope this helps

jim

Comment: I've changed it, and tried both an ActionResult and PartialView return type, and neither worked. It's still loading the whole partial in the window and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

If you're intending the submit to fire the Ajax.BeginForm, you'll need to include it in the form with curly braces.  Currently your submit is not within the form.

Comment: Also, you probably want to consider upgrading to MVC 2.0

Comment: Changed the code to include {}s and put the submit button with the {}s, but it's still loading everything into the window and not the div.